# Miller effect conceptual confusion

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, cmos

I have a confusion which has made me wonder that my whole basis of electronics understanding is wrong.

I was looking for an intuitive explanation of the right half plane zero on internet( see link http://tinyurl.com/neg5fe4  <--This is important) and got confused about **feedback and feedforward current** . So, tell me if I'm right: a capacitor is bidirectional in a sense that current can flow in both ways in the miller capacitor. This is unlike a resistor where current only flows from high voltage to low voltage?

So the net current(in capacitor) = feedforward + feedback .

So, It's a superposition? So when I connect an ammeter with capacitor, i will get this net current right? Also  why does miller theorem only calculate feedback component? It's derivation is very generic, i guess(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_effect)

So how does one determine in which direction current flows in a capacitor?

Comment: *a capacitor is bidirectional ...* No that is not correct, forget the Miller effect for a minute. There is no difference in directional behavior between a capacitor and resistor. You're confusing AC and DC behavior. The Miller effect is strictly AC. For AC a capacitor and a resistor are just an **impedance**. The Miller effect also works with resistors ! Direction of current flow is only relevant for DC. Your first priority now is to know the difference between DC (static) behaviour and AC (varying, often sinusoidal) signals. **it is crucial knowledge**.

Comment: "So when I connect an ammeter **across capacitor**".  An ammeter measures current when it is connected in series

Comment: @FakeMoustache: Ok...i got confused between ac and dc...now what is difference in feedback and feedforward current?

Comment: isn't feedforward from input to output? so how do you say "the fed-back signal works to...". Assuming I assume what you said, what next?

Comment: Sorry, was confusing with positive feedback, forget that comment. So, forget about "current" for a moment. Just Feedback and feedforward: **Feedback** is where the signal is fed **back** so it travels **against** the flow of the signal. In Feedforward it travels in the same direction so **with** the flow of the signal.

Comment: you are confusing me bro, would you write in detail whole answer and how the dots connect in your answer?

Comment: only battery and electrolytic capacitor dielectrics are directional for current. ( ie. polarized)   regardless... MIller cap is seen from input and output like any cap

Comment: @FakeMoustache, Ok I got you last comment.

Comment: *only battery and electrolytic capacitor dielectrics are directional for current.* True but I think that comment will confuse this guy even more !

Comment: The directionality Tony refers to refers to the DC component, an electrolytic capacitor does not behave differently for a **signal** compared to a non directional capacitor. It does behave differently for the **DC voltage**. As long as you make sure a electrolytic capacitor has the right DC voltage (and not too much AC) it will work fine.

Comment: The book refers to blocking forward current which may cause a "zero" by buffering output with a Source Follower which also lowers output impedance and current drive capability in CMOS amps

Comment: I knew that...thats not my confusion....pls tell me how feedback and feedforward current are related and how we can mathematically visualize them and stuff..

Comment: the direct depends on the signal source with the lowest impedance

Comment: @FakeMoustache: u there??

Comment: hey guys did I write something wrong ,not allowed on stackexchange thats not allowed? Is that why nobody is answering me??

Comment: We're not here 24/7 so don't expect a continous flow of answers, we have a life also ;-) You got some more answers. Indeed you should treat the circuit as a whole. A feedback/foward does not change the mathematics in any way. I suggest you consult some other books/websites on the same subject to get some different explanations on the subject. And don't worry too much if it is not all clear directly, this takes time to learn and understand. Keep at it and some day you will say: AHA and "see" it ! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slide is a little bit misleading and difficult to understand.

The compensation capacitor Cc has a desired and an undesired effect on the operation of the circuit.

Its purpose is to generate a dominant pole to stabilize the circuit. This is achieved by making use of the miller effect, which works because the capacitor is across an inverting stage gm2.

The miller effect works because one terminal of the capacitor is driven by a signal amplitude that is multiplied by the gain of the second stage. If the gain was -10 and the one terminal is driven with 1V than the output would be at -10V resulting in voltage of 11V across the capacitor. From the viewpoint of driving circuit 10x the current is needed to charge the capacitor. The capacitor appears 10x larger. This is what we want to have. It's a result of feedback. The current flows of course in both directions depending on whether we want to charge or discharge the capacitor.

As a side effect a zero is introduced. It is not desired an can be avoided. Again assuming a rising voltage at the input of gm2 two things happen. First gm2 produces a current that flows from the output to ground. Second the voltage increase at the input of gm2 requires that Cc is charged. So a current flows through Cc to the output node. This current can under the right conditions be the same as the current produced by gm2. They cancel out. A zero is generated.

The zero can be avoided, because there is no for the current that flows through Cc to flow into the output node. If the output node is buffered (using a source follower for example) an additional node is created. The miller effect is retained and the zero avoided.

Comment: You said Charging Cc is reason for feedforward current, but what is reason for feedback current? Yes the intuitive explanation for miller is clear by you, but how current flows across Cc because of say, increased miller capacitance at input?

Comment: The feedback effect is not a current but a voltage. The feedforward effect indeed is a current through Cc.

Comment: Why are you saying that at Zero Location,the current produced by gm2 = current(feedforward) and not current produced by gm2 = curr(feedfor) + curr(feedb) at zero. I didn't get "feedback effect is not a "current but a voltage".To charge the  effective 11V across Cc, There will be current right (called feedback current across Cc)?

Comment: Forget the concept of the feedforward and feedback current and just try to understand what's going on.

Comment: ok..i got whats going on now what about currents?

Comment: ok..i got whats going on now what about currents? I can actually understand it in voltages but not current (i dunno why), So in voltages, we can look like this(tell me if I'm correct):There are 2 paths to output, 1 through Cc and other through amplifier. For calculating Vout, we must superimpose voltage contributions from both paths. Now, the point at which -Avin = Voltage via Cc path, a zero voltage created at output, hence zero. The miller poles are same input output theory you told.......Now, I'm facing the problem of explaining this concept in feedback and feedforward current terms.

Comment: Again, forget about a "feedback current". It does not help. There is feedback which creates a pole and feedforward that creates a zero. These effects are not necessarily related and therefore the zero can be avoided.

Comment: So my volatge explainination is correct right??

Comment: Shubham Chawla - what is your primary goal? If you need to analyze the complete circuit (transfer ratio) I agree with Mario to treat the circuit is a whole. Or is it just the current (and its components) through the feedback element you are interested in (for what reason ever)?

Answer (score 1):

*hey guys did I write something wrong ,not allowed on stackexchange thats not allowed? Is that why nobody is answering me??*

OK - let me try:

In the circuit diagram under discussion we have a transconductance device with a feedback capacitor. In contrast to an opamp the transconductor (term: OTA) has a large output impedance. And there is not only a current from the output to the input (feedback action) but also in opposite direction (from the inverting input to the output) which produces a voltage at the finite output impedance.

In this context, it is important to know, that the differential voltage between both inputs has a **finite** value - again, in contrast to the opamp where we always assume that this diff. voltage is so small that we can neglect it.

As you can see, we have two currents through the feedback capacitor. If we treat both currents separately it seems that they would be in opposite direction. However, if we take into account the correct sign of the driving input voltage and the minus sign of the output current we see that both currents have - indeed - the same direction.
And, yes - you can apply the superposition rule as long as the device works under linear conditions.

(Comment: It is recommended to treat (calculate) both currents separately and use superposition because the "feedforward current" is driven by a voltage - in contrast to the "feedback" current which is the output current of the gm device.)

Result: The current through the feedback element is much larger if compared with the (feedforward) current that is caused by the input voltage only. That is principle content of the MILLER effect.

Comment: 1) Ok opamps have "low" output impedance but this **will not stop feedforward current** flow, the other way round it will easy its flowing, BUT it will also divert this current from load (relatively higher impedance) to ground. It's just a current divider. 2)Current thru any bipole is unique and can only have one direction (and value) THEN, just in case it helps anyway you can apply superposition or any other math (base changing) or whatever. But this is only one representation of that unique single current.

Comment: 3) Naught or nearly that IS a finite value, anyway Miller is a theorem applying to linear networks, nothing to do with voltage levels at inputs or anywhere else, it is just true within linearity. And by the way nothing to do with AC or DC stimulus whatever they mean. 4)Simplifying a lot: while forward chain (gm, amplifier, A, G whatever you call it) has "enough" gain feedback will rule. After that when you don't have enough forward gain anylonger (higher frequencies usually) feedforward will prevail THAT'S exactly the RHP zero @Shubham Chawla was asking about.

Comment: to 1) Yes - that is true, of course. But my point was (I am not sure if I could make it clear) that in case of opamp this current is NOT driven by any input voltage (virtual ground) but, instead, it will be soaked by the inverted output voltage. In contrast, for OTAs we have (a) an output (feedback) current and superimposed a voltage-driven current.

Comment: Oh yes now I see what you mean, which is true as long as opamp open loop gain is high enough to hold true virtual ground approximation.

Comment: @LvW : as you said, the feedback and feedforward current actually have the same direction. So on what basis do we distinguish feedback and feedforward current?

Comment: The answer is given in the "comment section" of my detailed answer: superposition of two currents, which are driven by two different sources.

Comment: @LvW, thank you. So the definition of feedforward and feedback current is based on the which voltage/current source driven the current not the direction of current itself?

For example, normally, feedforward should be from input to output but in this case the feedforward current is from output to input when the input voltage is negative.

Comment: Yes - that`s correct.